# If I am part of a family trust but was under age can my grandmother or mother settle in court for a lump sum of money and have me taken off the will

Tags: united-states, california, wills, trusts-and-estates, family

My great grandfather left a family trust; my grandmother says she sold my portion in court to the trustee while I was under age. Is that legal? I am from California, U.S.A

Comment: Was your grandmother your legal guardian at that time? Anyway, details might depend on the exact terms of the will. You might want to take a copy of it to an attorney specialized in inheritance law. They might tell you if selling your part of the trust on your behalf was legal or not.

Comment: It isn't material what state you live in or were born in, what matters is the state under whose laws the trust was created.

Comment: It would take far more facts to discern than are available, such as the terms of the trust, the nature of the transaction, etc. There is no way to tell, or even to make a reasonable guess about what is happening, from the information in this question.

Comment: You should hire a lawyer, not ask on an Internet forum.